# FM tuner API for Iphone and Blackberry

Tags: iphone, ios, blackberry, java-me, symbian

I would like to create FM tuner for all major mobile platforms(Black berry,Android,Iphone,J2ME).Are they  support third party app for FM tuner?Have any FM radio API reference for Blackberry and Iphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search will show that [some Blackberry phones (but not all) are equipped with FM tuners that can be accessed programmatically](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/37518/FM_Radio_Overview_1930956_11.jsp). iPhones do not have tuners built in.